# Kotlin basic math on each item of a list

Tags: list, kotlin

I'm not really understanding how to use Lists in Kotlin correctly, for even simple things.

Say I've got a list of Doubles, and I want a list that is 2 times as big. So for [1.0, 2.0, 3.0] I want [2.0, 4.0, 6.0] as the output.

What's the "correct" way to do that?

I can figure out a way to go stepwise through the List and add each part to a new mutable list like so:

```
fun main() {
    val list1 = listOf<Double>(1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0)
    val list2 = mutableListOf<Double>()
    list1.forEach{
        list2.add(it*2.0)
    }
    print(list1)
    print(list2)
}
```

https://pl.kotl.in/WORk6Wdqu for that code in a playground.

But it seems like this is "not the right way to do it", as in it would go very slow on big lists, or just takes a lot of line compared to the right way, or that we now have two lists (in the end, I will just be shoving the values back into my "list1")

Comment: `fun main() = print(listOf(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0).map { it * 2.0 })` :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`map` applies the expression to each item and makes a new list from the result.

```
val list1 = listOf<Double>(1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0)
val list2 = list1.map { it * 2 }
```

> or that we now have two lists (in the end, I will just be shoving the values back into my "list1")

If you really have very large lists, you don't even want one of them and might want to look at `sequences`. But I think you're jumping the gun and worrying too much.

Keeping things in immutable objects as much as possible is good practice, but that means making new lists sometimes.